# Let $f: \mathbb D \to \mathbb D $ be holomorphic.Suppose for that $z_\circ\in \mathbb D$ we have $f(z_\circ)=z_\circ$ and $f'(z_\circ)=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb D \to \mathbb D $ be holomorphic.Suppose for that $z_\circ\in \mathbb D$ we have $f(z_\circ)=z_\circ$ and $f'(z_\circ)=1$.

What can you say about $f$?

My intuition says $f$ should be identity function but one of my friend is saying his answer is $f(z)=z_\circ+ e^{i\theta}z$ using Schwarz lemma.

Can anybody help me in this problem, whether I am correct or he is?

If I'm correct then how to proceed.

Comment: he is not right, note that we don't know $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: tell me your approach, please

Comment: @Humam, ok! I don't know too, it passed too time since I studied this. I will think here.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g=\varphi^{-1}\circ f \circ \varphi$, where $\varphi$ is a Mobius transformation that moves $0$ to $z_0$, for example
$$
\varphi(z) = \frac{z+z_0}{1+\overline{z_0}z} .
$$
Then $g(0)=0$ and (chain rule, several times) $g'(0)={\varphi^{-1}}'(z_0)f'(z_0)\varphi'(0)=f'(z_0)=1$. So $g(z)=z$ by the Schwarz lemma and thus $f(z)=z$ also.

Comment: $f=\varphi g\varphi^{-1}=\varphi\,\textrm{id}\,\varphi^{-1}=\varphi\varphi^{-1}=\textrm{id}$

Comment: How do you get $g(z)=z$ using Schwarz lemma?

Comment: @Member: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Comment: But from there you will get $g(z)=az$ for some $a\in \mathbb C$  and $|a|=1?$
How do you eliminate $a$?